# Vue2: How to redirect to another page using routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

How can I redirect to another vue page from my script code. I am using router.push() but cannot redirect to my desired vue page.

Following is my source code.

**src/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HomePage from '@/components/HomePage'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'IndexPage',
      component: IndexPage
    },
    {
      path: '/homepage',
      name: 'HomePage',
      component: HomePage
    }
  ]
})
```

**src/components/IndexPage.vue**

```
<script>
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

  export default {
    name: 'IndexPage',
    methods: {
      redirectUser() { // this method is called on button click
         if (1 == 1)
         {
            router.push('/homepage');
            //this.$router.push('/homepage');
         }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

After running this code I am getting error which states:

> ReferenceError: router is not defined at eval

**src/main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

window.Vue = Vue

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Furthermore, I can access that same link from browser http://localhost:8080/#/homepage. But cannot redirect to it from my script code.

Comment: did you import the `router.js` file into your `main.js`?

Comment: Yes I've imported that.

Comment: You may use instance method like this.$router.push({name: 'HomePage'}) ?

Comment: did you add the `router` option in your root vue instance in main.js file?

Comment: @RuChernChong you were right somehow. I imported src/router/index.js file into my src/components/HomePage.vue and it worked.

Comment: Congrats. Do you want me to write an official answer and you Mark it as accepted? @ZainSMJ

Comment: Yeah that would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanx for the feedback friends. I was not importing my router file on my vue. The updated line of code is:

**src/components/IndexPage.vue**

```
<script>
  import router from '../router/index.js'  // Just added this line and code works !!

  export default {
    name: 'IndexPage',
    methods: {
      redirectUser() { // this method is called on button click
         if (1 == 1)
         {
            router.push({name: 'HomePage'})
         }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I guess you answered your own question before I could :D

Answer (score 5):

import Vue and VueRouter
and then call

```
    Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

then in your method,

```
    this.$router.push({name: 'HomePage'})
```

EDIT

You need to import both Vue and Vue Router if you want to use it in your code, that's why you are getting router is not defined at eval.
And also use

```
this.$router.push('/homepage');
```

Try this in your **src/components/IndexPage.vue**

```
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

  Vue.use(VueRouter)

  export default {
    name: 'IndexPage',
    methods: {
      redirectUser() { // this method is called on button click
        if (1 == 1)
        {
           this.$router.push('/homepage');
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use your component instance property to access the router:

```
this.$router.push({name: 'HomePage'})
```

And do you have it in your app?

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Getting almost same error for this solution also. 
> TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of undefined at eval

Comment: @ZainSMJ You need to include your router to the main app as well.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please review my main.js file and guide me through.

Comment: @ZainSMJ I don't see your code, you may play here https://jsfiddle.net/q9bjx5os/ and try to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
function redirect(page) {
  window.location.href = page;
}
```